# GCMS Peak Identification: Online or Open Source / Free Programs?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, software, mass-spectrometry

Suppose I have a GCMS peak graph for a component, what are possible options to figure out what the molecule may be?

Any tips about good software that will do this? I do know that for many compounds there is a hit in the NIST library, but how does one go about automatically checking the library?

Google came up with [OpenChrom](https://www.openchrom.net/features). Has anyone used this? The peak library in it is unfortunately not accessible in the free version.

Comment: [This is what I use](http://www.chemcalc.org/mf_finder/mfFinder_em_new). For a formula, at least. Other methods then allow me to deduce structure. MS *can* give you many structural clues, depending on the ionization method.

Comment: @DGS Thanks. Correct me if I am wrong, but that tool only seems to use the MW based on the top peak, right? Isn't there a way to use the other lower peaks as well?

Comment: Type in the mass of a lower peak?

Comment: @DGS Thanks. Maybe I'm not getting the right way to use this. e.g. Say for an unknown sample I've a GCMS consisting of several MW / peak height pairs. What one would want to do is identify a hit from the library that approximates this distribution most closely, right? If I just enter a lower peak's MW in this tool it just produces a hit to a low MW compound but that's not what we want right? Its just a low MW fragment produced from the original high MW compound we are trying to identify, correct?

Comment: That's right. Maybe I wasn't completely clear on your intension. I don't think there is a library for MS data like that. I could be wrong. ChemDraw includes a MS prediction program, but not the other way around, as far as I know.

Comment: @DGS I know that most GCMS manufacturers include programs that will do such matching for you but those are expensive & propreitory. OTOH, NIST does have a library but not sure what tools to use to access it.

Comment: Oh, okay, my bad.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but a good resource for spectroscopic identification is http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_list.cgi

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [Golm Metabolome Database](http://gmd.mpimp-golm.mpg.de/)?
It is a collection of GCMS mass spectra. The focus is on metabolites.

However, on their webpage is the entry "Decision Trees". If you follow the link, there is the option to enter your own mass spectra information and receive a prediction of functional groups in the measured substance.
This might be of help to identify your molecule.
There are more details in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golm_Metabolome_Database).

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you elaborate on the good and bad sides of "Golm Metabolome Database".

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @IͶΔ. I have extended the answer. Is that more helpful?

Comment: Yes, much better. Thank you and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

[OpenChrom](https://openchrom.net/) is free of charge, but the [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/srd) db is not. That is why you need to have the NIST db already installed on your system.

Have a look at this [tutorial](https://spectrometrylab.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/openchrom-and-nist-db/).